# Can I mark a folder as mountpoint-only?

Tags: linux, mount

I have a folder `~/nas` which I usually use `sshfs` to mount a network drive on. Today, I didn't realize the share hadn't been mounted yet, and copied some data into it. It took me a bit to realize that I'd just copied data into my own local drive rather than the network share. Is there some way to mark in the system that this folder is supposed to be a mount point, and to not let anyone copy data into it?

I tried the permissions solution here: [How to only allow a program to write to a directory if it is mounted?](https://superuser.com/questions/348887/how-to-only-allow-a-program-to-write-to-a-directory-if-it-is-mounted), but if I don't have write access I also can't mount anything to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you are ***not*** root, you simply could revoke the write permission for the *~/nas* directory for yourself and use sudo for elevated mounting:

```
$ chmod u-w ~/nas
$ cd ~/nas
$ touch test
touch: cannot touch `test': Permission denied
$ cd ..
$ sudo mount -t fuse -o <options> sshfs#<user>@<host>:/mount/path/ ~/nas
$ cd ~/nas
$ touch test
$
```

The idea behind all that: ~/nas as the mount path would have the permissions assigned to it while the destination is not mounted, thus preventing modifications by you (as long as your user does not have root privileges). The mount command (needs root privileges to run) temporarily modifies the folder's permissions to whatever the destination's permissions are set to, allowing write access for your user.

Comment: `sshfs` is a [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) filesystem, which doesn't work with `mount`. Part of the purpose is so I don't have to be root to mount the nas (since I'm using my ssh credentials to mount it anyway)

Comment: IIRC there are issues without mounting SSHFS as root.

Comment: I've never had any issues with an SSHFS mount, and I've never done it as root.

Comment: @collin so even using `sudo` is not an option?

Comment: @rob the problem is not the mount itself but the requirement to remove the user's write permission for the mountpoint. As the OP already found out, this would not work with `fusermount`. But it would work with `mount.fuse`

Comment: @syneticon-dj It is an option, I was just trying to figure out if there was a better way to handle the mounting check. Your mount command doesn't work for me, I sort of remember seeing something like `sudo mount <path> -t fuse <some options for sshfs> ~/nas`, but now I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @Collin I had to fix the mount line in my post, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 7):

We used the **immutable**-flag to protect the directory even for root-access.

```
chattr +i /vmdata/backup
```

This way even root is not allowed to write there when nothing is mounted. 
After mounting the disk, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the later suggested answer there:

> 1st: Check the with the mount command, if the directory is mounted

`mount | grep <mountpoint>` will tell you if there's anything mounted there.  If you really want to make sure the right thing is mounted there you can use a more complex regex, but I don't think there's a need to.

Comment: It would be nice if I could prevent anything from writing to it, but I do mostly interact with the NAS though scripts, so this could be added to the common ones.